# Regex: How best to combine regex's with conditionals (in Python)?

Tags: python, regex

I already have the regex's (and some behaviour based around each of them, individually, using Python's `re.findall()` and `re.search()` for IPv4 address, IPv6 addresses, mail server name, and private IP address. A private IP is one that falls in the following range:

```
10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255
172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255
192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255
```

The regex;'s:

```
#Mail server ([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.){2,3}[a-zA-Z]+ 
#Private IP (?:10|127|169|172\.(?:1[6-9]|2[0-9]|3[01])|192\.168|169\.254)\..*
#IPv4       \d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}
#IPv6       ([a-z0-9]{1,4}:+){3,5}[a-z0-9]{1,4}
```

Now I need to add some flow control. Given that with regex's we can match globally, non-greedy etc, combine patterns etc. I'd prefer to take advantage of this fact (combining regex's into a single Python expression) rather than perform each individually with multiple if/else's. Here's a typical string:

```
Received: from [192.168.0.140] (n11649196059.netvigator.com. [116.49.196.59])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPSA id w12sm4743917pbs.68.2015.06.04.16.21.51
        for <someaddress@gmail.com>
        (version=TLSv1.2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Thu, 04 Jun 2015 16:21:52 -0700 (PDT)
```

Here's the pseudocode for what I'm trying to do, for each string like the above:

```
if any IPv4 or IPv6 address matches:
    if firstMatch is not private: # Private meaning matches "Private IP" regex above
        return firstMatch
    else:
         #continue through string to look for another IP address
         if found nextMatch: 
            if nextMatch is not private:
             return nextMatch
            #else continue through string to look for another IP address, 
            #again checking for privacy. If none found, just return firstMatch
    return firstMatch

# no valid IP address found, look for mail server now    
else:
    if matchedAmailServer:
        return mailServer
```

In the example string above, 192.168.0.140 is private, so I'll proceed through the string until I find the next IP address. This next address is - 116.49.196.59 - is not private, so that's what I return. If, on the other hand, there were no second IP address in the string, I would want to return mx.google.com

How best to intelligently use Python's `re` functions here, with a view to maximizing regex capability and minimizing the number of if/else's?

Comment: I strongly recommend you _don't_ combine regexps. Your code is a lot easier to maintain than one monster "clever" regexp.

Comment: But if you show an example of what your input looks like and what you want to get out of it, you'll probably get some good suggestions. E.g., your `firstMatch`/`nextMatch` code looks awkward, but there's no telling where they come from or how to formulate a better suggestion.

Comment: @alexis fair point. Post updated with an example string.

Comment: You want the first non-private IP address, and if there are none, then the first private?

Comment: @alexis Correct (noting that the first private will generally precede the first non-private in the string). And in the absence of both, the mail server (if present).

Comment: And by "mail server" you mean the fully qualified name that follows the word "by"?

Comment: @alexis that's right. My regex for the mail server is a little flimsy, but yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can distinguish the classes that you are interested in, just search for them in order:

```
ip_addr = re.findall(RE_ADDRESSES, response)
non_private = [ x for x in ip_addr if not re.match(RE_PRIVATE, x) ]
if non_private:
    return non_private[0]
# They're all private: return first one
elif ip_addr:
    return ip_addr[0]

mailserver = re.findall(...)[0]
return mailserver
```

Note that since `return` terminates execution, I didn't use `else` clauses-- this keeps the code from nesting too deeply. You can add them if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks. Thing is though: I have a regex for ALL IPv4 address, and a regex for privates (privates are a subset, defined by the range I've now added in my post). So I don't have a RE_NON_PRIVATE regex as such, and I imagine that  to create one would be tough. With a regex for all and a regex for privates, what can we do?

Comment: No prob, then you collect all IPv4 addresses, and make a sublist of the non-private ones (if any). See revised answer. Filtering lists in this way is a good technique to have. (You can also use `filter`, but I prefer conditional list comprehensions.)

Comment: The non-intuitive reversing of the conditionals is a stroke of genius. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, it's a common pattern though: Find the general case, then subtract the special case and you have the rest. It's often useful to do first the specific, then the general.